# Android Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

Hi friends i want to implement the action bar exactly like this(only text), IF i select any of the text, the blue border which is at Balloons comes to that particular text and rest of the things to be normal,How to implement this.please help me.

Comment: It is action bar with tabs See [here](http://feigdev.com/blogs/2) and [here](http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example)

Comment: sorry Abhi, my application not working, it is showing an error like unfortunately stopped, i dont know why...

Comment: Check your log cat for what the error is

Comment: i checked, it is showing like this :  11-20 10:06:59.736: E/AndroidRuntime(735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean the Navigation tabs.

Everything you need is explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: I want to add ActionBar to my existing project that project is developed in androd 2.3, then how to do this??